# Python substring search not working

Tags: python, string, generator

name is a list of tuples which are len(1) and contain string

When I use:

```
if word in (name[0] for name in t):
        return name[0]
return None
```

then I am getting None(search unsuccessful)

But with the same value of word and the same list if I use:

```
gen=(name[0] for name in t)
for i in gen:
    if word in i:
        return i
return None
```

The search is successful and I get the required result. Why such a divergent behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

In `if word in (name[0] for name in t)` you're actually searching for the exact string not substring, i.e whether the generator contains that exact word or not.

Change it to use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(word in name[0] for name in t):
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> t = [('foo',), ('bar',)]
>>> any('oo' in name[0] for name in t)
True
>>> 'oo' in (name[0] for name in t)
False
>>> 'foo' in (name[0] for name in t)
True
```

Note that if you want to return the matched item then it's better to use second code of yours(just remove the unnecessary genexpr, directly loop over `t`), if you just want to check for existence of a substring then use `any()`. Here's an example using `enumerate` and `next` with a generator expression for learning purpose:

```
>>> item = next((name[0] for name in t if 'oo' in name[0]), None)
>>> if item is not None:                                         
    print item
...     
foo
```

Comment: But how to `return name[0]` this way?

Comment: @tobias_k Oops! I missed that part, updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks that helped but that behaviour is pretty strange....why does it check the exact string this way, a semantic reason for that?

Comment: @svetaketu That syntax actually checks whether the generator contains that item or not. It is equivalent to: `lst = [name[0] for name in t]; 'oo' in lst`, only difference is that no list is created and it short-circuits as soons as a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that in the first example, `name` is not in scope in `return name[0]`.

If the code returns `None` instead of throwing an exception, you have another (global?) variable called `name`.